# Find the value of c for the system to have

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

(i)  no solution
(ii) a unique solution
(iii) infinitely many solutions  with one parameter
(iv) infinitely many solutions with 2 parameters

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    c^2-c & 0 & c & c^2 \\
    0 & 1-c^2 & c^2 & -c\\
    0 & c^2-1 & c & c\\
    c^2-c & 0 & c & 2c\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I understand that we are supposed to use Gaussian elimination and solve this linear system by considering entries. Is it possible for this linear system to have infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 0):

$R_1\times-1+R_4 \longleftrightarrow R_4$ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    c^2-c & 0 & c & c^2 \\
    0 & 1-c^2 & c^2 & -c\\
    0 & c^2-1 & c & c\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & c(2-c)\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$  We see if $c \neq0,2$ then the original system has no system. However, if $c=0$, we arrive at the system$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ which has infinitely many solutions with two parameters: $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
=x_1\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ On the other hand, if $c=2$ we arrive at $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
    0 & -3 & 4 & -2\\
    0 & 3 & 2 & 2\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    $$
$R_2+R_3 \longleftrightarrow R_3$ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
    0 & -3 & 4 & -2\\
    0 & 0 & 6 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    $$ which possesses a unique solution

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
    2\\
    2/3\\
    0\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$ There is no value of $c$ for which this system will have infinitely many solution with one parameter.